# Why Putting Method Parameter Value to Other Variable?

Tags: java

I notice in some of programmer code, They put the parameter value of their method to another variable before they manipulate the value. as per below

```
//method math addition
public void mathAdd(double value1, double value2){

double val1      = value1;     //why value1 put into val1?
double val2      = value2;     //why value2 put into val1?
double totalAdd  = 0;

totalAdd = val1 + val2;        //why dont directly taken value1 and value2
                               //from parameter instead?

System.out.println("Answer : " + totalAdd);

}
```

is there any reason to do that, because instead we can do as this:

```
//method math addition
public void mathAdd(double value1, double value2){

double totalAdd  = 0;

totalAdd = value1 + value2;

System.out.println("Answer : " + totalAdd);

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, there is no point. In other cases, you may want to save the value of the arguments for something else that comes later in the method.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it was done for aesthetics. For some, looking at that code may be easier to read compared to jumping back and forth wondering where a variable is defined.

Comment: i think it can be one of the reason also.